# What does ריש חזית mean?

Tags: translation, mathematics, vilna-gaon

I'm reading(/trying to read) the introduction to the Vilna Gaon's איל משולש (his geometry textbook). The first two words are ריש חזית.

What does ריש חזית mean?

If it helps, the phrase is immediately followed by a passuk from kohelet and then a midrash.

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20365&st=&pgnum=155&hilite=

Comment: Extremely closely related: judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6094/3

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, user67187, and thanks for bringing your question here. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"ריש חזית" means "the beginning of מדרש חזית". The *Midrash Rabbah* on *Shir Hashirim* and *Kohelles* is often called מדרש חזית because it begins with *derashos* on the *pasuk* "חָזִיתָ אִישׁ, מָהִיר בִּמְלַאכְתּוֹ" (Mishlei 22:29). The author of the introduction you are reading begins by quoting [*Shir Hashirim Rabbah* (1:8)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37460&st=&pgnum=5).

Comment: Is it common for it to stand alone the way it does here i.e. for the text to simply say ריש חזית and not בריש חזית כתוב or something like that?

Comment: @user67187, I don't know. What I'm more used to when someone starts by quoting something like this is to introduce it with a "ב" prefix as in "בריש מדרש חזית" or with "איתא ב" as in "איתא בפ"ק דערובין". I don't recall seeing this format too much, but I suppose it's not uncommon.